# Tkinter The buttons gets misplaced in a pc with a higher resolution

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, getsystemmetrics

I made a tkinter application in my pc which has 1366 x 768 resolution then converted to exe and sent to another pc with 1920 x 1080 resolution. There, buttons were misplaced, got inside the labelframe - image in the center while i made an effort to use settings that will make them stay in their own places, so i avoided as much as possible things like place() and used thing that are same in all. By the way my app resizes itself according to the pc's resolution, so even if i run it in i a 4k resolution pc its meant to work and take the same places in the pc's screen.

```
"""
Pillow, pywin32, pyglet & pygame must be installed to run this code (click F5
to run)

To install those module you must write those codes one by one to CMD  
(command prompt) running as adminitrator (requires internet connection) :

- pip install pillow
- pip install pygame
- pip install pywin32
- pip install pyglet

If it gives ‘pip’ is not recognized as an internal or external command
error you must install it before running the codes aboves, to install it
follow this steps : https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

"""
#TO ADD A CUSTOM FONT(#ttf(font file)must be in the same place with the app
#which is 'RINGM___.TTF'):

import pyglet,tkinter
pyglet.font.add_file('RINGM___.TTF')

import PIL
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
from tkinter import ttk

#TO DISABLE PYGAME WELCOMING MESSAGE:
#import os
#os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "hide"

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

import time



# --- functions ---

def passit():
    pass

def backtonrml():
    RArrowbtn2.configure(image=useImg4)
    RArrowbtn2.update()

def backtonrml2():
    RArrowbtn.configure(image=useImg7)
    RArrowbtn.update()

def change_pic_2():
    RArrowbtn2.configure(image=useImg5)
    RArrowbtn2.update()

def change_pic_3():
    RArrowbtn.configure(image=useImg8)
    RArrowbtn.update()

def kill():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    root.destroy()


def Oncursound():
        pygame.init()
        LocksoundObjempt = pygame.mixer.Sound('slash sound rotwk.mp3')
        time.sleep(0.05)
        LocksoundObjempt.play()
        
        

        

def OnCursor():
    change_pic_2()
    Oncursound()        
        

def OnCursor2():
    change_pic_3()
    Oncursound()
    
    
    


root = Tk()


screen_x = int(GetSystemMetrics(0))
screen_y = int(GetSystemMetrics(1))

window_x = GetSystemMetrics(0) - 325
window_y = GetSystemMetrics(1) - 155

posX = (screen_x // 2) - (window_x // 2)
posY = (screen_y // 2) - (window_y // 2)

geo = "{}x{}+{}+{}". format(window_x, window_y, posX, posY)

root.geometry(geo)
root.config(bg="gray15", cursor='arrow red red')
root.update()

#root.overrideredirect(1)
print(root.winfo_width(),"x",root.winfo_height())
print(GetSystemMetrics(0),"x",GetSystemMetrics(1))





imgW2 = root.winfo_width() - 250
imgH2 = root.winfo_height() - 150


imgW3 = root.winfo_width() - 225
imgH3 = root.winfo_height() - 125



img5=Image.open('3nCc3Sq.png')
image5=img5.resize((imgW2,imgH2))
bg=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image5)
  
# Create label

labelframe = LabelFrame(root,text="Click Left or Right Arrow to switch the theme", height=imgH3, width=imgW3, labelanchor='n',font = ("Ringbearer",19), fg='#5E66D6', bg="gray15")
labelframe.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")

label = Label(labelframe, image=bg,highlightbackground="red3",bd=0,relief='flat',)
label.pack()
label.image = bg

imgW = 97
imgH = 274

img4=Image.open('1.png')
image4=img4.resize((imgW,imgH))
useImg4=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image4)

img5=Image.open('2.png')
image5=img5.resize((imgW,imgH))
useImg5=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image5)

img6=Image.open('3.png')
image6=img6.resize((103,280))
useImg6=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image6)

#--------------------------------------------

Img7 = img4.transpose(PIL.Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
Img7.save('4.png')
root.update()
Img7_2 = Image.open('4.png')
image7 = Img7_2.resize((imgW,imgH))
useImg7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image7)

Img8 = img5.transpose(PIL.Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
Img8.save('5.png')
root.update()
Img8_2 = Image.open('5.png')
image8 = Img8_2.resize((imgW,imgH))
useImg8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image8)

Img9 = img6.transpose(PIL.Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
Img9.save('6.png')
root.update()
Img9_2 = Image.open('6.png')
image9 = Img9_2.resize((imgW,imgH))
useImg9 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image9)

  
def change_pic():
    pygame.init()
    btnsoundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('rotwk button sound.mp3')
    btnsoundObj.play()
    RArrowbtn2.configure(image=useImg6)
    RArrowbtn2.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
    RArrowbtn2.configure(image=useImg5)
    RArrowbtn2.update()

def change_pic2():
    pygame.init()
    btnsoundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('rotwk button sound.mp3')
    btnsoundObj.play()
    RArrowbtn.configure(image=useImg9)
    RArrowbtn.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
    RArrowbtn.configure(image=useImg8)
    RArrowbtn.update()

    

RArrowbtn = Button(root, image=useImg7,command=change_pic2,  activebackground="gray15")
RArrowbtn.config(borderwidth=0,highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0, relief='flat', bg='gray15') 

RArrowbtn.place(relx=.06, rely=.5, anchor="center")



RArrowbtn2 = Button(root, image=useImg4,command=change_pic,  activebackground="gray15")
RArrowbtn2.config(borderwidth=0,highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0, relief='flat', bg='gray15') 

RArrowbtn2.place(relx=.94, rely=.5, anchor="center")

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('LotrOpening-2.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)



RArrowbtn.bind("<Enter>", lambda eff: OnCursor2())
RArrowbtn.bind("<Leave>", lambda eff: backtonrml2())



RArrowbtn2.bind("<Enter>", lambda eff: OnCursor())
RArrowbtn2.bind("<Leave>", lambda eff: backtonrml())



root.mainloop()
```

It look so in the pc i made it:

[image: in the pc i made:]

and so in the other pc:

[image]

(I removed the menu)

Comment: both `pack` and `grid` would make this easier than `place`.  With `place` you have to do a lot of the math yourself.

Comment: Yes, this `250` and other values are pixels with respect your 1080p display, with a different resolution it will be redirected different. Use something like `grid()` or `pack()`.

Comment: That happens because you used the `Place` geometry manager. If you switch to `grid`/`pack` it should solve your problem.

Comment: how can i do that with pack that pls? any example, i seriously have no idea